# Rx concatWith() return only first Flowable result

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have posted all methods they are working separately , but I face issues with the first one, where I concatWith() two flowables

```
    return userFavouriteStores()
    .concatWith(userOtherStores())
   .doOnNext(new Consumer<List<StoreModel>>() {
      @Override
      public void accept(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull List<StoreModel> storeModels) throws Exception {
        Log.i("storeModels", "" + storeModels);
      }
    })


public Flowable<List<StoreModel>> userFavouriteStores() {
return userStores()
    .map(UserStores::favoriteStores)
    .flatMap(storeId -> storeDao.storesWithIds(storeId))
    .map(stores -> { // TODO Konvert to Kotlin map {}
      List<StoreModel> result = new ArrayList<>(stores.size());
      for (se.ica.handla.repositories.local.Store store : stores) {
        result.add(store.toStoreModel(StoreModel.Source.Favourite));
      }
      return result;
    });  }

public Flowable<List<StoreModel>> userOtherStores() {
return userStores().map(UserStores::otherStores)
    .flatMap(storeId -> storeDao.storesWithIds(storeId))
    .map(stores -> {
      List<StoreModel> result = new ArrayList<>(stores.size());
      for (Store store : stores) {
        result.add(store.toStoreModel(StoreModel.Source.Other));
      }
      return result;
    });}
```

updated method :userStores() is used for favorite and other stores ,

```
  private Flowable<UserStores> userStores() {
return apiIcaSeResource
    .userStores()
    .toFlowable(); }

  @GET("user/stores")
Single<UserStores> userStores();
```

Comment: what does the `userStores()` method do? make sure the `Flowable` fires `onComplete`, otherwise `concat` will not work

Comment: What do you expect to happen I wonder?

Comment: @Habib Okanla each of them emits 3 item ,to have 6 items in one flowable

Comment: @yosriz I have updated and posted userStores() method

Comment: @yosriz I have updated and posted userStores() method  and the second method and the second part of concat() is not reaching

Comment: @i.ss, I can't see your edits, make sure you've apply your changes

Comment: @yosriz I have updated sorry

Comment: you need to provide full details, what is apiIcaSeResource
    .userStores()? is it retrofit call? some custom Observable of yours?

Comment: @yosriz updated

Comment: @yosriz any idea?

Comment: I tried Flowable.concat() / Single.concat() I got both results but separately  ,I need combined in one Flowable

Comment: I'm still not sure what you expect exactly, I would guess each Flowable emit single List item, and with the concat you would expect 2 emission of List (meaning 2 lists)

Comment: @yosriz Each Flowable emits List,and each List could include multiple items, 
for example 3 item,and as a result I want to combine two list as one list which could contain items ,as each List could contain 3 items ,Did I explain clearly ?

Comment: @yosriz I think the main problem is that both Flowables come from the same source userStores() ,any idea could be useful for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comments follow up, and additional information, you don't have a problem specifically with the `concat()`, I'm assuming it is work, it's just not the tool for what you want to achieve here.

`concat()` will not concatenate two lists to a single list, but rathe will first emit all items by first `Flowable` and only then items emitted by second `Flowable` (hence you must have `onComplete` so concat will know when `Flowable` is end, what I asked in the begining).

in order to combine the lists together, I would suggest to zip both stores `Obesrvable`s (favorites/ others), and then simply combine to list to have single output of combined list.
Besides that, as you pointed out, as both stores `Observable`s comes from `userStores()`, you will invoke the network request twice, which definitely not necessary. you can solve it using `publish()`, that will share and multicast the network result to both `Observable`s, resulting with single network request.

to sum it up, I would rather recommend to use Single here, not `Flowable` as you don't have backpressure consecrations. something like the following implementation:

```
Observable<List<StoreModel>> publish = userStores()
        .toObservable()
        .publish(userStores ->
                Single.zip(
                    userFavouriteStores(userStores.singleOrError()),
                    userOtherStores(userStores.singleOrError()),
                    (favoriteStores, otherStores) -> {
                         favoriteStores.addAll(otherStores);
                         return favoriteStores;
                    }
                )
                    .toObservable()
        );
```